# Hide signup on login

Tags: php, authentication

When users are logged in I want to hide the signup button, right now it displays :

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php echo 'Welcome: '.$_SESSION[ 'firstname']; ?>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="signup.php">SIGNUP</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

But I want , when they are not logged in, to display Login instead of signup, and when they logged in, it displays the

```
<?php 
    echo 'Welcome: '.$_SESSION['firstname'];
?>
```

Instead of signup.

How can I do this?

Comment: With an [`if()`](http://www.php.net/if)

Comment: Who upvoted this? This is so basic and simple that it makes you wonder if any thought was put into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you could use the session variable to determine if the user is logged in or not.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['firstname']))
    echo "Hello " . $_SESSION['firstname'];
else
    echo "SIGNUP";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this [*Assuming you have* `session_start()` *on the top of your PHP code*]

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['firstname']))
{
?>
<li><a href="signup.php">SIGNUP</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```